# Is there a way to make Javascript redirect the page after cliking refresh( the session already expired)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, session

I kept a counter in my Javascript, when the counter reaches 0, it will trigger the following AJAX call:

```
  function logout2() {
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
       url: "app/logout",
       timeout: 20000,
       success: function() {
            ;
       },
       error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ajaxErrorHandler(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
       }
})
```

}

As you will see, it will log out from the server side officially, however, the page will remain unchanged, which means the page remains unchanged, it will NOT automatically be redirected to login page. Only when the user does something specific(like click on a button on this page) will trigger a pop-up saying "session timeout" and redirect the user to the login page.

However, now I am requested to enhance this a little bit, after the AJAX function above has been called, not only user actions like clicking a button will trigger the redirect but also when user refresh the page it will do the same.

I tried a little but really have no gain. Currently after page expires, if I refresh, it will not pop-up session-time out dialog, nor it will redirect to the desired page.

Is there anything I can do at JavaScript or Ajax level to achieve after user refresh, I will be able to also pop up that dialogue then redirect?

Comment: Why not have the message pop up as soon as the user is logged out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using

**Edit**

```
success: function() {
        alert ("You have been logged out");"
        window.location.href = "you_have_been_logged_out.jsp";  // or something
   },
```

However the normal way to do this would be to use a servlet filter to check whether the user is logged in (a value stored in a session variable)

Comment: probably I didn't make it clear. If I add that as yo u suggest, then after my local counter reaches 0, then the page will automatically be redirected. The system requirement enforces that the page remains there unchanged after expires, only when user triggers some actions will the redirection happen.

Comment: see my update then.  Of course some other dialog would be nicer

Comment: I know what you mean, but the requirement is that that pop-up dialogue won't be shown until user refresh the page. In your case, that pop-up will show whenever the ajax call returns successfully.

Comment: the normal way to do this would be to use a servlet filter to check whether the user is logged in (a value stored in a session variable)

Answer (score 1):

you can add a flag to your jsp like

```
<%
if(session.getAttribute('flag')==null)
   response.sendRedirect('desired/page');
%>
```

it will redirect the page to the redirect page whenever the session flag is null on page request. So when the user clicks refresh button it gets redirected. Just make this flag null at server side at logout and enable it at login time.

Comment: just change it at server side in your logout code. This will have no effect on the page functioning but as soon as the page refreshes this will redirect to the page specified. You mentioned that you do not want to change anything in the page when the session expires but only when some action like refresh is done.

Comment: even if you change some thing in page using js, it will not be there at page reload. since everything gets reloaded on a new request.